# msbuild package target issue

Tags: .net, msbuild, msdeploy, psake

I have an MVC 4 web app with VS2012, msbuild and am creating a build script with psake. I've created a publish profile in VS that packages up the project into a zip file. Running it from within VS works fine. However, running it from the command line, I get the following error:

Executing package
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.32559
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.32559]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.P
>   ublishing.targets(2006,11): error MSB4100: Expected
>   "$(_DeploymentUseIis)" to e valuate to a boolean instead of "", in
>   condition "$(_DeploymentUseIis) And ($(L ocalIisVersion) >= '7')". 
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudi
>   o\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets
>   [E:\bitbucket\mypopsales\src\MyPop
>   Sales\ConsumerWeb\ConsumerWeb.csproj] Error: 07/25/2013 07:29:41: At
>   E:\bitbucket\mypopsales\tools\psake\psake.psm1:139 char:9 +
>   throw (" Exec: " + $errorMessage) +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ [<<==>>] Ex ception: Exec: Error
>   executing command          msbuild $csprojFile /t:Package /p:Plat
>   form=AnyCPU /p:Configuration=$config /v:q       . ERROR: 1

I have Web Deploy 3.5 installed on the box via WebPI. Any idea on how I can resolve this issue? The relevant section of the build script is as follows:

```
task package -depends test {    
    $csprojFile = "$solution_dir\$consumer\$consumer.csproj";   
    exec{ msbuild $csprojFile /t:Package /p:Platform=AnyCPU /p:Configuration=$config /v:q } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Joy...after spending a couple of hours on this, it turns out to be as simple as adding:

/p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0

to the parameters list.